# Python - how to convert a list to log(list)

Tags: python, list, logarithm

I have a list of values and would like to convert it to the log of that list or pass the log of a list to a function.  I'm more familiar with R and you can usually throw some () around anything.  When I attempt this in Python I get the error:

```
TypeError: must be real number, not list
```

List looks like this:

```
pressures[:5]
Out[11]: [1009.58, 1009.58, 1009.55, 1009.58, 1009.65]
```

It doesn't really matter where I try to take the log, I get the same error...in a function:

```
plt.plot(timestamps, log(pressures))
plt.xlabel('Timestamps')
plt.ylabel('Air Pressure')
plt.show()
```

Whilst parsing data:

```
pressures = log([record['air_pressure'] for record in data])
```

Comment: `numpy.log` will perform the operation on each element of the list and return a numpy array.

Comment: or if you want to see the actual pressures on a logarithmic scale that is also an option: [`plt.semilogy`](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.semilogy.html)

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple of ways to handle this. Python has some basic, built in functions in the `math` module. One is `log`. It takes a float or an int as a parameter and outputs a float:

```
> from math import log
> log(20)
2.995732273553991
```

To process a list with this function, you'd need to call it on every item in the list:

```
> data = [1, 2, 3]
> [log(x) for x in data]
[0.0, 0.6931471805599453, 1.0986122886681098]
```

On the other hand, and I mention this because it looks like you're already using some related libraries, `numpy` can process an entire list at once.

```
> import numpy as np
> np.log([1, 2, 3])
array([ 0.        ,  0.69314718,  1.09861229]) # Notice this is a numpy array
```

If you want to use `numpy` and get a list back, you could do this instead:

```
> list(np.log([1, 2, 3]))
[0.0, 0.69314718055994529, 1.0986122886681098]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can only use `log()` with a single number. So you'll need to write a loop to iterate over your list and apply `log()` to each number.

Fortunately, you have already written a loop that, with some modification, will do the trick.  Instead of:

```
pressures = log([record['air_pressure'] for record in data])
```

Write:

```
pressures = [log(record['air_pressure']) for record in data]
```

Comment: If you have a list of `pressures` you want the `log` of already produced, and given `log()` is the complete operation, I'm partial towards `pressures_log = map(log, pressures)`. But it is equivalent to the above.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to do logs and you have a list of integers you can use the math lib for that.

```
import math

my_data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

log_my_data = [math.log(x) for x in my_data]

print(log_my_data)
```